# Firestore transaction contention but with different documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For example, I have 10 documents in my collection. 10 requests come in near the same second and will run the same query. They each will start their own transaction that will try and read 1 document, and then delete that document. Given the firestore documentation with document contention, it is made to seem like contention errors happen when more than one transaction occurs on the same document X amount of times (it is not documented how many times).

> Cloud Firestore resolves data contention by delaying or failing one of the operations.

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/transaction-data-contention

However, in this case since 1 of those transactions committed, I am assuming the other 9 that tried to operate on that same document, will retry because the document from the query was "changed" and couldn't commit. Then the next 9 transactions will try to do the same thing, but on another document, and this will continue until all requests finished deleting 1 document and there are no more active transactions.

Would the retry rules of these transactions that kept getting retried, be ABORTED due to contention, even though it's been a different document each time? Or would these transactions just keep getting delayed and retried because the contention is happening on different documents on each attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transaction_failure), the transaction will retry a "finite number of times".  This number is dependent on how the SDK itself is configured, which may be different for various SDK platforms and versions.  **It doesn't matter which contended document(s) caused the retry.  The max number of retries is absolute for that transaction in order to avoid excessive work.**

Newer versions of the SDK allow configuration of the number of retries (e.g. [Android 24.4.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#firestore_v24-2-0) lets you specify [TransactionOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/TransactionOptions)).